# Compare 2 csv files and check for first 2 columns, if it matches ask the user to decide to override or not and then proceed to next row

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv

I have a use case where I have 2 CSV files with some rows in each CSV file, and they have three columns each. Compare the 2 csv files for first 2 columns and if it matches then ask the user input if he wants to override the row in the first csv file with the values from second csv file, if not abort the operation.

First time when I run the python code it should update the csv file with the new values from the 2nd CSV file to first csv file, but for consecutive runs of my python code I have to check if first 2 columns match and ask the user to decide if he needs to override the values or not, since now the first csv file will have rows from first csv file.

My code:

```
import csv
import sys

def csv_file_copy():
   csv_file = input("Enter the CSV file needs to be updated ")
   csv_file_cp = input("Enter the csv file from where the data needs to be copied ")
   csvfile = open(csv_file_cp, 'r',encoding="utf-8-sig")
   reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
   csv_file_orig = open(csv_file, 'r',encoding="utf-8-sig")
   reader2 = csv.reader(csv_file_orig)
   res = []
   for row in reader:
     print("This is row", row)
     for row2 in reader2:
       print("This is row2", row2)
       if (row2[0] == row[0] and row2[1] == row[1]):
         user_input = input("Store type and store number already exists in the csv file, continue? y/n ").lower()
         if user_input == "y":
           res.append(row)
         elif user_input == "n":
            print("Aborting operation")
            sys.exit(1)
       else:
        res.append(row2)
     res.append(row)
     continue
   print (reader)
   with open(csv_file, 'w') as csv_file1:
      writer = csv.writer(csv_file1, delimiter=',')
      for row in res:
        writer.writerow(row)

csv_file_copy()
```

When the code is executed second time against the same 2 files the second `for` loop runs only once thereby matching only one value but there are about 10 values that is matching which doesn't work for me.

Comment: There are a couple of issues in your code. To name only one: `reader2` is an iterator that is exhausted once you went through it once. So there's no chance you will get beyond the first row of `reader` without an exception - or am I missing something? I don't know how big the files are, but it seems to me that you might want to read `reader2` into a dictionary to overcome that obstacle.

Comment: @Timus Thank you for your reply, could you give me an example how I can use it or probably correct my code to achieve this? Yeah you are right the reader2 iterator exhausts after matching the first line

Answer (score 0):

If the `csv_file_orig` is not too big (or your available memory too low) then you may store the whole contents into a list.

Instead of

```
reader2 = csv.reader(csv_file_orig)
```

You'll use

```
csv_file_orig_lines = list(csv.reader(csv_file_orig))
```

Afterwards you may iterate through `csv_file_orig_lines` list as many times as you want.